# Как заменить статический массив на динамический c++

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Прошу помочь.

Пытаюсь статический массив в динамический. В результате выводится массив адресов, а не элементов. Чем глубже капаю, тем больше путаюсь, поэтому прошу проверить корректность кода и подкорректировать в случае необходимости.

Еще ввод и вывод данных должен быть осуществлен в текстовый файл. На каком этапе кода это нужно вводить?

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray(int *arr, int arrSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i){ //Вывод значений входящего массива
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int *createArrOfOddNum(int *arrIn, int sizeIn) {
    int *outputArray = new int[sizeIn/2];
    int value;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeIn; ++i) //Перебор всех элементов
    {
        if (arrIn[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            value = arrIn[i]; //Если элемент нечетный, то добавляем его в новый массив
        }
        else
        {
            value = arrIn[i]; //Если элемент четный
            int j = 1;
            bool flag = true; //Условие выполнения цикла while, пока число не станет нечетным
            while (flag)
            {
                if (i + j < sizeIn)
                {
                    value += arrIn[i + j]; //Если элемент не последний, то прибавляем к нему следующий в массиве
                    if (value % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        flag = false; //Если после прибавления элемент стал нечетным - прекращаем While
                    }
                }
                if ((i - j >= 0) and (flag == true)) //Если следующий элемент прибавить не удалось, то прибавляем предыдущий элемент
                {
                    value += outputArray[i - j]; //Прибавляем предыдущий элемент
                    if (value % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        flag = false; //Если число стало нечетным - выход из цикла
                    }
                }
                j += 1; //Переход на следующий элемент массива в цикле While
            }
        } //Конец работы с четным элементом
        outputArray[i] = value; //Запись новых значений 
    }
    return outputArray;
}

int main(){

    int array_in[] = {2, 1, 4, 7, 6, 11, 5, 6};
    const int arrSize = sizeof(array_in) / sizeof(array_in[0]);

    int N = 8; // Задается размер массива
    int *inArray = new int[N]; // Выделение памяти для исходного массива
    int *outArray = NULL; //Присваивание NULL обозначает, что память не выделена
    int outArray_size;

    inArray[N] = array_in[arrSize];

    outArray = createArrOfOddNum(inArray, N);

    cout << "initial massive:" << endl;

    printArray(array_in, arrSize);

    cout << "final massive:" << endl;

    printArray(outArray, arrSize);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"Чем глубже капаю, тем больше путаюсь"* - это не удивительно, ведь вы не составили [mcve], который тут займет аж 2 строки...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде куча странностей. К примеру

```
inArray[N] = array_in[arrSize];
```

это просто присвоить один элемент другому. Но даже для компилятора очевидно, что эти оба индекса за пределами массива. А это уже UB (по простому - компилятор говорит голосом Кеши "ага, вот ты как" и позволяет себе многое).

Может это попытка скопировать один массив в другой?

Дальше

```
int *outputArray = new int[sizeIn/2];
```

размер массива половина от sizeIn, смотрим дальше

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeIn; ++i) //Перебор всех элементов
{
   // удалил
   // а дальше выход за пределы массива, когда i > sizeIn/2
   outputArray[i] = value; //Запись новых значений
}
```

а потом ещё и выведем его с неверным размером

```
printArray(outArray, arrSize);
```

Что именно делает код - от меня ускальзывает, но работать оно не может.

Может Вам перейти на std::vector?

Comment: о, а ещё минусаторы подъехали

Comment: `Может это попытка скопировать один массив в другой?`
Да, заменила на ` inArray = array_in; `, изменила размер массива, все заработало, спасибо.

Comment: в этом случае Вы просто скопировали указатели. И сделали утечку (так как выше есть строка `int *inArray = new int[N];`)

Comment: (обычно спасибо здесь - это нажать треугольник вверх и галочку напротив ответа)

Comment: Треугольник вверх мне не доступен пока что.

Comment: А как скопировать корректно?

Comment: по хорошему - использовать std::copy (для ценителей си  - memmove/memcpy), но в Вашем случае обычный цикл будет более чем достаточен